# rational canonical form with respect to elementary divisors vs. rational canonical form with respect to invariant factors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{Q^{2n}} \to \mathbb{Q^{2n}}$ or $T:\mathbb{R^{2n}} \to \mathbb{R^{2n}}$.
Let $A$ be a $2n$ x $2n$ matrix and define $T:=Av$.
Suppose $\chi_T=\mu_T=(x^2+a)^n$, where $\chi_T$ and $\mu_T$ are the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial, respectively.

Is it now the case that the rational canonical form with respect to elementary divisors is the exact same as the rational canonical form with respect to invariant factors?

It seems to me that both rational canonical forms will be nothing more than the companion matrix of $\chi_T$. Is this correct?

Is this true anytime the characteristic polynomial is just composed of one irreducible?